# Length of copper wire in 1 lb spool

Tags: materials, density

I was asked the following question in my introductory chemistry class:

> The diameter of metal wire is often referred to by its American wire gauge number. A 16-gauge wire has a diameter of $\pu{0.05082 in}$. What length of wire, in meters, is there in a $\pu{1.00 lb}$ spool of 16-gauge copper wire? The density of copper is $\pu{8.92 g/cm^3}$.

First I converted the imperial measurements to metric. $\pu{0.05082 in} = \pu{0.12908 cm}$, $\pu{1 lb} = \pu{0.45359 kg}$, according to Google. So I can use $\pi r^2 h$ to calculate the volume (and thus, using density, calculate the mass) of one meter of wire, I figure the radius to be $\pu{0.06454 cm}$. The equation becomes $V = \pi \times (\pu{0.06454 cm})^2 \cdot \pu{100 cm}$, which equals $\pu{0.41654 cm^3}$. So that's the volume of one meter of wire.

Using the density of copper $(\pu{8.92 g/cm^3})$, I figure the mass of one meter of wire to be $\pu{3.72 g}$. If $\pu{1  lb} = \pu{453.59 g}$, then converting $\pu{3.72 g}$ to lbs gives me $\pu{3.72 g} \cdot \frac{\pu{1  lb}}{\pu{453.59 g}} = \pu{0.01 lbs}$. So assuming I did everything correct, one meter of wire is a hundredth of a pound, so in one pound of wire there is $100$ meters.

Answer (score 2):

### Find a function of length depending on mass

Conversion factors:

- $2.54 ~\mathrm{\frac{cm}{in}}$
- $454 ~\mathrm{\frac{g}{lb}}$

Constants:

- Wire diameter $d = 0.129~\mathrm{cm}$
- Density of copper $\rho = 8.92~\mathrm{g\, cm^{-3}}$

Thus, our function $l(m)$ for the wire length from the wire mass in pounds reads:
$$ l(m) = m \cdot 454~\mathrm{\frac{g}{lb}} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi d^2 \rho}$$

### Evaluate the function

Since I'm too lazy to evaluate something like this by hand (and since I somehow had to record this thought process and did not want to waste the processed remnants of a dead tree) there is a small python script available to do this for you, which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/tschoppi/f2f2e372f080478d3da4) and which, if you run it using the command `python3 wires.py`, will give you the following output:

> Wire length of 1.00 lb of 16-gauge wire: 9.71 m

---

(Bonus: You can run the command as `python3 -i wires.py` and will then be dropped into an interactive python shell, where you can call the `wirelength` function as many times as you wish using different masses for the wire.)